# How to get p value after ROC analysis with pRoc package?

Tags: r, spss, roc, proc-r-package

After ROC analysis of a set of data, how to calculate p-value? With the same statistics, I saw that the p-value can be output in SPSS. 
The sample code is as follows:

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
head(aSAH)
#    gos6 outcome gender age wfns s100b  ndka
# 29    5    Good Female  42    1  0.13  3.01
# 30    5    Good Female  37    1  0.14  8.54
# 31    5    Good Female  42    1  0.10  8.09
# 32    5    Good Female  27    1  0.04 10.42
# 33    1    Poor Female  42    3  0.13 17.40
# 34    1    Poor   Male  48    2  0.10 12.75

(rr <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b, plot=T))
# Setting levels: control = Good, case = Poor
# Setting direction: controls < cases
# 
# Call:
#   roc.default(response = aSAH$outcome, predictor = aSAH$s100b,     plot = F)
# 
# Data: aSAH$s100b in 72 controls (aSAH$outcome Good) < 41 cases (aSAH$outcome Poor).
# Area under the curve: 0.7314
```

#### Edit:

The p value calculated in SPSS is 0.000007, but the p-value calculated by `verification::roc.area()` is 0.000022546, is the calculation method of `roc.area()` and SPSS inconsistent?

```
levels(aSAH$outcome) <- c(0, 1)
library(verification)
ra <- roc.area(as.numeric(as.vector(aSAH$outcome)), rr$predictor)
ra$p.value
# [1] 0.00002254601
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify your question significantly, especially after you received an answer. If you have a followup question about the difference between roc.area and SPSS, that's a new follow-up question, so you should ask a new question.

Comment: @Calimo Thank you for your concern about the question's quality. However, actually the OP made the edit for valid further clarification and announced it to me in a comment to my answer. Thereafter I tried to triage them to CV. Since their question there was [downvoted an closed as off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/468450/163114) I have taken the liberty of roll back your rollback and answering the question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no option to get the p-value in `pROC::roc`, you may set option `ci=TRUE` to get confidence intervals instead. `pROC::roc` yields an invisible output that you may grab by assigning it to an object.

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
rr <- pROC::roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b, ci=TRUE)
```

Using `str(rr)` reveals how to access the `ci`:

```
rr$ci
# 95% CI: 0.6301-0.8326 (DeLong)
```

So you have already a confidence interval.

Moreover, you can also get the variance, using `pROC::var`<sup>*</sup>, from which you could calculate a standard error manually.

```
(v <- var(rr))
# [1] 0.002668682
b <- rr$auc - .5
se <- sqrt(v)
(se <- sqrt(v))
# [1] 0.05165929
```

<sup>* Note, that there is also a bootstrap option `pROC::var(rr, method="bootstrap")`.</sup>

This is identical to the one calculated by Stata,

```
# . roctab outcome_num s100b, summary
# 
# ROC                    -Asymptotic Normal--
#   Obs       Area     Std. Err.      [95% Conf. Interval]
# ------------------------------------------------------------
#   113     0.7314       0.0517        0.63012     0.83262
# .
# . display r(se)
# .05165929
```

where [Stata Base Reference Manual 14 - `roctab`](https://www.stata.com/manuals14/r.pdf) (p. 2329) states:

> By default, `roctab` calculates the standard error for the area under
>   the curve by using an algorithm suggested by DeLong, DeLong, and
>   Clarke-Pearson (1988) and asymptotic normal confidence intervals.

Once we have the standard error, we also may calculate a *p*-value based on the *z*-distribution ([Ref.](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1319291-p-value-for-auc-after-roctab-command)).

```
z <- (b / se)
2 * pt(-abs(z), df=Inf)  ## two-sided test
# [1] 0.000007508474
```

This *p*-value is close to your SPSS value, so it's likely that it's calculated with an algorithm similar to Stata (compare: [IBM SPSS Statistics 24 Algorithms](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjAx6HLsNvpAhWbThUIHfihB3UQFjABegQIARAB&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fpublic.dhe.ibm.com%2Fsoftware%2Fanalytics%2Fspss%2Fdocumentation%2Fstatistics%2F24.0%2Fen%2Fclient%2FManuals%2FIBM_SPSS_Statistics_Algorithms.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3IAOF1ZyS-eUOmnfOq4lUJ), p. 888:889).

***However,*** the calculation of the *p* value of a ROC analysis might be controversial. E.g. the method you show in your edit (see also first link below) is based on a Mann–Whitney U-statistic.

You might want to dig a little deeper into the subject before you decide which method is best suited for your analysis. I provide you with some reading suggestions here:

- [Does AUC/ROC curve return a p-value? (Cross Validated)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/386468/163114)
- [Which standard error formula for the area under the ROC curve should I use? (Cross Validated)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/167397/163114)
- [Differences between cross validation and bootstrapping to estimate the standard error of the AUC of a given ROC curve (Cross Validated)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/166853/163114)
- [Comparison of Three Methods for Estimating the Standard Error of the Area Under the Curve in ROC Analysis of Quantitative Data (Hajian-Tilaki and Hanley 2002)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12449360/)
- [Testing Statistical Significance of the Area under aReceiving Operating Characteristics Curve forRepeated Measures Design with Bootstrapping (Liu et al. 2005)](http://www.jds-online.com/files/JDS-206.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for jay.sf, but the p-value I got from roc.area () in the verification package is inconsistent with the p-value in SPSS. The p-value calculated in SPSS is 0.000007, but the p-value calculated by roc.area () is 0.000022546, is the calculation method of roc.area () and SPSS inconsistent?

Comment: @dbcoffee This is indeed an interesting question, probably SPSS and `roc.area()` are using different methods to calculate the p-value, can't tell you more. Since this is now mainly a statistical issue, I suggest to [ask on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a question about the reasons for the difference in p-values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and the related information you provided. This is the best answer I have obtained so far. Maybe I can write a function to get p value by the above code.